# Correct setup for developing in JavaFX with Jfoenix 9.0.9

Tags: javafx, netbeans, jfoenix

I want to develop a JavaFX application with Netbeans and Scene Builder integration and I would like to use Jfoenix 9.0.9. I've tried using Netbeans 8.2 but the latest version of Jfoenix is not old enough, and by downgrading to Jfoenix 8 I would lose the JFXTabPane functionality which would be a bummer.

I need help setting up the proper software to use. So far I've tried JDK 832 with NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans Apache with both this JDK and the latest (11.0.4), but can't seem to make it work. Could it be possible to follow a guide? It would be fine if I had to create the project from scratch on Maven or Gradle for the Apache Netbeans, I just want to make sure it's the right Java version and the IDE can work with both settings. I'm a bit lost, thanks in advance

Comment: This guide may help you set up JavaFX 11+ with NetBeans: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I will be working on NetBeans 8.2 JDK 8 and JFoenix version 8.0.8, luckily I can import the latest Jfoenix build to Scene Builder and it still works on NetBeans... for some reason. Scene Builder also crashes when I use TabPane components, the workaround is to browse the .fxml file you want to work on, not open it directly through the NetBeans double click functionality...

This is all a bit messy, but it's the best I can do and I don't have too much time to spare in trying stuff out unfortunately. Thanks for the help Slaw